# Command Line Activity Display

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there anyway to view the commands executed in the command line when you are interacting the user interface in windows such as clicking on a short cut?

Answer (score 0):

For most applications there is no behind the scenes execution of command line apps in the way you're thinking. Both GUI apps and command line apps are ultimately doing the same thing: interacting with the API of the operating system. So when you click an application shortcut, there aren't a bunch of headless command line apps starting up to handle it. There's direct interaction with the Windows API which takes action, such as launching a new process to open the requested app. If you want to see the arguments that running commands (headless or with a UI) were started with, try this in your terminal:

```
WMIC path win32_process get Caption,Processid,Commandline
```

Comment: mentioning logs might be useful--as many gui apps can provide debug info in the form of a log written to either stdout or a file which can be observed in the shell.